# How to make API calls

Tags: rest-api, api, soap-api

I want make an API call with an external website to login to external web site using salesforce custom object data on click of a button on a custom button.

Can  I know how to start with when an a API is given to us.

Comment: Could you share some more details; which language do you use? What kind of API call do you want to do? What have you tried so far? Are there any specific problems you run into?

Comment: I am new to Web services stuff ....
I have to login into a external website and insert a records when i click a button in a custom object(in salesforce).
for login and for performing DML operations i would be given an API 

So I wants some documents or some steps how to work with an  API  to communicate with external application

Comment: So are you gonna create records in another system from Salesforce (so are you gonna write code on the Salesforce side)? Or are you gonna work on the external system?

Comment: yes I am going login and perform the following operations
create record,delete  records and retrieve records in external system
I would write code in salesforce to perform all the above opeations

Answer (score -1):

You can use i.e. [REST API](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Getting_Started_with_the_Force.com_REST_API) or [SOAP API](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/SOAP_API), you'll need to authenticate via OAuth 1st but it's well described in SFDC doc.

Comment: the question is about making API calls to an external system.

Comment: I misunderstand the question. If there is API on the mentioned external site you can use this. From apex you can call both SOAP and REST api calls. Of course it is also possible to make custom integration via HTTP calls but both SOAP and REST are transparent. Take a look here https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_callouts.htm Everything depends on 'external site'. I don't know what is there exactly.